# What's wrong with my ResNet50 on two machines?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, resnet

Firstly, I trained a ResNet50 to be a six-class classifier from scratch on Kaggle, and got like this. 
[image: screenshot of Kaggle kernel]

As you can see, the accuracy of training set and validation set improved steadily.
And after that, I rented a cloud host on the internet for a better GPU(1080ti), and copied my code (I uploaded my Jupyter notebook). And then I runned it. But strange things happened. My validation accuracy is extremely unsteady and always fluctuated widely (around 0.3). Here's the screenshot.

[image: screenshot of the host]

And also, the training on the host is much more difficult than on Kaggle kernel.
Here are the screenshots after some epochs.(actually the host's one is trained over much more epochs than the Kaggle's one)
[image: kaggle(after some epochs)]
[image: host(after some epochs)]
And here's my codes of ImageDataGenerator.

```py
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.1,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.1
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    validation_split=0.1
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    base_path,
    target_size=(300, 300),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training',
    seed=0
)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    base_path,
    target_size=(300, 300),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation',
    seed=0
)
```

Comment: Do you provide your validation set separately or do you just specify validation_split size?

Comment: I just specify validation_split size. I've edited my question, posting my codes of Data Generator. @BashirKazimi

Comment: You're using generators to create your data with different augmentations all together, it will be hard to get reproducible results. I am assuming that is the reason for the change in results. If you want reproducible results, I suggest you use the generators to create data and save it to disk first. Then, you could load the data (directly or with generators but without augmentation) and train your models. This way, you are sure you are training on the same set of examples every time and might get similar results.

Comment: You mean the host splits the data size differently from Kaggle kernel? Does it make such big difference on performance? Actually, on Kaggle I ran around 60 epochs and got an accuracy over 0.7. But on the host I ran around 120 epochs and still got a lower and fluctuant(0.4~0.6) accuracy. (by the way, I've ran it many times both on Kaggle and the host. Kaggle always performed well and the host always performed badly)@BashirKazimi